# Average values mongodb

Tags: mongodb, average

I am trying to get the average of the values field from my data.
I have nested document. With some values. I want to get the average value of field"value" from this document. and want to use this value in c# application

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c49f398fc0078178c76705b"),     // my json data
        "Time_Created" : ISODate("2019-01-24T17:19:20.205Z"),   // date
        "Test_ID" : "1",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "Device_id" : "1",
                        "Total_wires" : "5",
                        "Cables" : [
                                {
                                        "TAG" : "4001",
                                        "Value" : 24.3

                                },
                                {
                                        "TAG" : "4002",
                                        "Value" : 21.3

                                },
                                {
                                        "TAG" : "4003",
                                        "Value" : 21.3

                                },
                                {
                                        "TAG" : "4004",

                                        "Value" : 21.3

                                },                                                            
                                {
                                        "TAG" : "4005",                                        
                                        "Value" : 100.3

                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}

db.collection_name.aggregate( [  {$unwind: "$data"}, { $group : { _id : "$data.Cables.Value", avgValue: { $avg : "$data.Cables.Value"} } } ] );
```

I'm getting this result:

```
{ "_id" : [  24.3, 21.3, 21.3, 21.3, 100.3 ], "avgValue" : null }
```

But this is what I'm expecting

```
{ "_id" : [  24.3, 21.3, 21.3, 21.3, 100.3 ], "avgValue" : 37.7 }
```

`37.7` being the average of all the values `24.3`, `21.3`, `21.3`, `21.3`, and `100.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the pipeline below.

```
[
    { 
        '$project': {
            'values': '$data.Cables.Value',
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': '$values'
    }, {
        '$addFields': { 'avgValue':
            { '$avg': '$values'}
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

db.collection_name.aggregate( [{  '$project': { 'values': '$data.Cables.Value', }}, { '$unwind': '$values' }, { '$addFields': { 'avgValue':    { '$avg': '$values'}   } } ] )

worked well !

But one issue is the incoming value field is string. So need some kind of conversion string to int and then average